# Smart card selection for digital signature

Tags: javascript, pdf, digital-signature

I am mantaining a VB6 Windows application which digitally signs PDF documents by launching a JS file, located in the Javascripts subfolder of Acrobat 9.0. Now my Customer wants to plug another smart card reader to the PC which hosts the application, with its own smart card containing certificates related to a second person who will sign certain type of documents.

My question is: how can I programmatically choose, from my JavaScript code, the smart card reader I want?
In my JavaScript code I do the following:

```
    //Initialize the signature handler
    var myEngine = security.getHandler("Adobe.PPKLite");

    //Obtain the available certificates
    var ids = myEngine.digitalIDs;
    var myCerts = ids.certs;

    //Find the certificate I want to use to sign
    for(var j=0; j<myCerts.length; j++)
    {
        if(myCerts[j].subjectCN == "SMITH JOHN")
        {
            oCert = myCerts[j];
            break;
        }
    }

    //Log to the signature engine by passing the certificate I want to use 
    //and the slot where the corresponding smart card reader is plugged
    myEngine.login( { oParams: { cDIPath: ACROSDK.sigDigitalIDPath,
            cPassword: ACROSDK.sigUserPwd,
            iSlotID: 1,
            oEndUserSignCert: oCert 
            } 
        } );

    //Digitally sign the document with the certificate I chose
    sigField.signatureSign({oSig: myEngine,
            bUI: false,
            oInfo: { password: ACROSDK.sigUserPwd,
                location: ACROSDK.sigLocation,
                reason: ACROSDK.sigReason,
                contactInfo: ACROSDK.sigContactInfo,
                appearance: "FirmaRPPR"
                }
        });
```

Why do I receive a General Error when executing signatureSign? Which is the correct way to assign the iSlotID parameter when logging to the signature engine or, alternatively, the cTokenLabel parameter?

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Mind you, I have no experience in using Acrobat scripting, but in PKCS#11 slot id would refer to the id of the smart card reader connected to the computer, and token label would be assigned label to one of the smart carts in that slot/reader, which can vary from PKCS#11 implementation to another.

And the easiest way to find out the label of the PKCS#11 token would be to configure the PKCS#11 DLL you're using as a Security device in Firefox browser and see the label field in the configuration. But that would be just to get you going in the right direction.

You can write a short C program against the PKCS#11 and use `C_GetSlotList` and `C_GetSlotInfo` to find out the slot id's and token labels, [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuelei/entry/dump_pkcs11_slot_info) is an example of that. It should not be a problem to port that code over to VB. Also there is [NCryptoki](http://www.ncryptoki.com/) that you can use to interface the PKCS#11 DLL.